# How do I customise the WYSIWYG (TinyMCE) field for Admin UI in KeystoneJS 5 -- adding plugins, changing CSS?

Tags: tinymce, keystonejs

KeystoneJS offers the option of a WYSIWYG field type

> This field inserts a string path into your schema based on the Text
> field type implementation, and renders a WYSIWYG editor in the Admin
> UI using TinyMCE

How do I edit the TinyMCE-based WYSIWYG editor plugins and appearance? On [this page](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/fields-wysiwyg-tinymce/#editorconfig) in the KeystoneJS docs it says we can pass in an object, which I assume is named editorConfig

> editorConfig
>
> Default: {}
>
> Accepts any TinyMCE config options. These will be passed to
> tinymce.init and can be used to override Keystone.js' default editor
> appearance and functionality.

but it's not working for me.

```
const editorConfig = {
 selector: 'textarea',
 menu: {
  format: { title: "Format", items: "forecolor backcolor" }
 },
 toolbar: "forecolor backcolor"
};


text: { type: Wysiwyg, editorConfig},
```

And when I try to load in CSS

```
const editorConfig = {
    selector: 'textarea',
    content_css: '/tinymce.css',

};
```

that CSS is never loaded.

I tried using `config` in place of `editorConfig` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's in the docs, it's not yet in the version released to the public.  It should be in a few days, they say:  https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/2486#issuecomment-595178710